# How do I make the Google Docs voice typing stay active when on?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-docs

In Google Docs, if you are using Chrome, you can turn on voice typing. This setting is in the `tools` menu and it is called `voice typing`.

The problem with this thing is you need to click it to activate it, and if you don't say anything for five seconds or so, it turns itself off. This is really annoying because the whole reason I'm using speak to type is so I can use the mouse and keyboard less. But it turns off every 5 Seconds so I have to keep on clicking the button to turn it back on again.

Since this is all done in HTML, I figure there's probably some way to inspect the HTML and modify it so that it doesn't turn itself off every 5 Seconds. I'd prefer it to stay on until I click it off, but if that's a technical challenge for some reason, I would be fine with extending the timeout duration to a minute or two instead.

I've looked at the source myself and unfortunately it appears to be uglified. For this reason, I'm unable to figure out where this duration comes from. How can I modify the front end to increase the duration?

Comment: You should be able to write a plugin to modify it, if it's not determined by the server

Comment: been trying to solve this also, in the console if you go to sources and find the link to https://docs.google.com/static/document/client/js/521339307-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js at the end, you can minify it, then at line 80565 of the minified version you can find I think the source of it....

Comment: function HFh(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, k, l, m, p, q, r) {
    var u = this;
    S.call(this);
    IFh(f);
    this.Ma = q;
    this.Ja = new Dw(this);
    this.ha(this.Ja);
    this.la = new Qx;
    this.ha(this.la);
    this.wa = new Qx;
    this.ha(this.wa);
    this.Na = d;
    this.F = k;
    this.ha(this.F);
    this.R = a;
    this.C = b;
    this.qa = c;
    this.Oa = e;
    this.na = l;
    this.za = g;
    this.V = m;
    this.Ba = p;
    this.ia = r || null;
    this.O = null;
    this.ea = [];
    this.L = 0;
    this.J = [];

Comment: this.X = this.W = 0;
    this.hb = j4f;
    this.H = new Qx;
    this.ha(this.H);
    JFh(this, this.na.F());
    Rx(this.H, this.F.F.V, function() {
        u.X = 0;
        KFh(u);
        LFh(u);
        u.V.start()
    });

Comment: Rx(this.H, this.F.F.L, function(v) {
        v = v.C;
        u.hb != j4f && GFh(u.C);
        MFh(u);
        var z;
        if (z = !v.Mt()) {
            z = u.V;
            var C;
            if (C = LEh(z.H)) {
                C = z.W;
                var E = C.C.Pa().getSelection().C;
                C = E ? 0 < fDc(C.C.ma(), E).C.length : !1
            }
            C ? (z.C = v,
            z.F && Dv(z.F),
            z.F = Cv(A(z.O, z), 2E3),
            z = !0) : z = !1;
            z = !z
        }

Comment: z && (T(kya).fb(v),
        T(iya).fb(NFh(u, v)),
        z = u.L,
        C = v.C.length,
        v.getReplacement() && (C += v.getReplacement().C.length,
        C -= v.getReplacement().F.length),
        u.L = z + C)
    });
    Rx(this.H, this.F.F.W, function(v) {
        OFh(u);
        for (var z = [], C = 0; C < v.C.length; C++) {
            var E = v.C[C];
            -1 == E.C.end ? (u.J.push(E),
            u.W = u.L) : z.push(E)
        }
        0 < z.length && T(eya).fb(z)
    });

Comment: Rx(this.H, this.F.F.R, function(v) {
        return void PFh(u, v)
    });

Comment: Rx(this.H, this.F.F.O, function(v) {
        if (v.errorCode == ok)
            3 > u.X ? (QFh(u, uYf),
            RFh(u),
            u.X++) : (u.kQ(),
            GFh(u.C),
            v = u.C,
            v.H || (v.H = oK("Voice typing turned off because it had a problem connecting.", Zi, !0)),
            mK.$a().postMessage(v.H),
            u.X = 0);
        else

Comment: switch (u.kQ(),
            GFh(u.C),
            v.errorCode) {
            case "no-speech":
            case "audio-capture":
                AFh(u.C.C, new rFh(2));
                u.za.C(2345);
                break;
            case "aborted":
                break;
            case "not-allowed":
                T(xh).Ra(!1);
                AFh(u.C.C, new rFh(1));
                break;
            default:
                throw Error("pB`" + v.errorCode);
            }
    });

Comment: Rx(this.H, this.F.F.J, function() {
        Tx(u.la);
        var v;
        if (v = 0 < u.L) {
            var z = u.Ba;
            if (null == z.C)
                v = !1;
            else if (v = z.C.Pa().getSelection(),
            v.C)
                v = !1;
            else {
                var C = z.C.ma();
                z = C.Ka();
                v = C.ce(wD(v).xb);
                v = qQ(z, v - 1) || fLd(z, v) ? !1 : v == LC(z, v)
            }
        }

Comment: v && u.F.F.L.dispatchEvent(new tEh(WDh));
        OFh(u);
        LFh(u);
        T(xh).Hc() && RFh(u, !1)
    })
}

Comment: The key is `mK.$a().postMessage(v.H), u.X = 0)` I think it appears to be an iframe where the audio is coming from